# Basic PhotoSwipe Carousel

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, jsfiddle, photoswipe

Im really new to jquery, only understanding some basic things.
At the moment im using the 'inline example' of photoswipe as a carousel.

things im having trouble with:

- remove the toolbar, but still keeping the error & loading.gif (could do with css, but think there could be a disable js solution?)
- add a custom next/prev/counter/caption/close link outside of the photoswipe container that I can style using css

*I know there is the documentation, but im not 100% sure how to implement it.*

If someone could possibly make me a jsfiddle with those 5 buttons outside of the inline photoswipe container it would be highly appreciated...

thank you in advance - josh

Comment: Did you download from their website or from their github? The download link on their website is outdated. And show us some code may be?

Comment: Set up a jsfiddle with what you have so far.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y73mC/

Comment: I dont really know where to start, or have anything... 
But I did make a jsfiddle (very embarrassed)

something like this `myPhotoSwipe.next();` or `myPhotoSwipe.previous();`?

Im using the debug inline version. (what does debug mean, can i use that?)

Comment: also john, its the github version